# How to handle cursorAdapter objects between activities effectively?

Tags: android

I'm currently developing my first Android application that depends heavily on the use of the underlying database (SQLite). The two tables within my database also have a designated (one-to-many) relationship. The structure is as following:

```
TableA
------
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
value INTEGER

TableB
------
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
valueRef INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES TableA(id)
```

In my application I need to display the contents of each table on separate pages (= activities), whereas the visualization happens by making use of `ListView` elements and an according `CursorAdapter` object.

A click on a list element of the first view (that handles the data from TableA) should open a new activity (as a subview) for the corresponding data of TableB.

My questions are:

1) How should I handle the exchange of the data between activities? Should I choose the simplistic way by using `Intents` or define a global object that can be accessed by all activities? What about huge table data sets, will this slow down the performance, because `Intent` is called by value and not reference!

2) How do I make sure, that if I delete an item from TableA, that the corresponding subview (that displays data from TableB) gets updated accordingly?

Comment: 1 ) Use `Intent` to pass the id and in new `Activity` just fetch item from db using that id

Comment: So strictly speaking, it would be bad practice if someone would try to map the data sets of all tables and their dependencies to according (custom) classes, and then pass these classes via `Intent`!

Comment: @neuronalbit absolutely, that’d be quite a bad practice. The data passed with an intent should be as small as possible. This way you ensure that everything is executed fast and UI is responsive.

Comment: `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` method has the `long id` parameter - just use it as an `Intent` "extra" when calling "TableB" activity